# Golang -- Deploy app using heroku app crashed H10

Tags: go, heroku

I need help...
I'm using heroku to deploy my golang app... but it seems my Procfile is not in the right format... here is the Procfile:

```
web: app-crm
```

everytime I deploy the app, it says succeeded but then after I access my endpoint, my app crashed with this message:

```
2021-11-15T08:00:49.813561+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-11-15T08:00:50.113738+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `app-crm`
2021-11-15T08:00:51.791188+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: app-crm: command not found
2021-11-15T08:00:51.920794+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2021-11-15T08:00:51.998349+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-11-15T08:00:52.006946+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-11-15T08:00:52.312734+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `app-crm`
2021-11-15T08:00:53.169065+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: app-crm: command not found
2021-11-15T08:00:53.278936+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2021-11-15T08:00:53.342179+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I tried to change how to access the port several times too, but it still doesn't work...

is there anyway I could fix it?

Comment: Do you have a `main` package in folder `app-crm`?

Comment: yes I do have main package @icza

Comment: Are you sure your `app-crm` binary gets installed? Try setting the `GO_INSTALL_PACKAGE_SPEC` env var, pointing to its folder. E.g. if its inside `cmd/app-crm`, set `GO_INSTALL_PACKAGE_SPEC=./cmd/...`

Comment: I actually placed my main.go file in the root folder, its the same level to the Procfile... I wonder if the GO_INSTALL_PACKAGE_SPEC=./cmd/... pointing to the main.go file?

Comment: The example I gave points to a `cmd` folder. You should put the `main` package into `cmd/app-crm`.